# Ubuntu 16.04.3 boots sometimes, but not all times

Tags: 16.04, boot, nvidia, lenovo, thinkpad

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04.3 onto a Lenovo Thinkpad T430. After troubleshooting some of the bigger, more known issues such as the nvidia driver versions, I am able to get it to boot about 25% of the time, but I would like to make this more consistent. I think I have finally hit a wall in my ability to troubleshoot this further on my own.

I have used Boot Repair and generated the following pastebin link:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/26117900/

Does anyone have a suggestion on where I should start looking?

Answer (score 1):

After more googling, I noticed a lot of people with similar problems had BIOS issues. After resetting BIOS to defaults, it cleared up all boot issues.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off installing it again correctly.
Prerequisites : Internet through LAN, or Android phone with internet.

1. Create bootable media, boot from media.
2. Start Ubuntu Install, make sure to user proper option from install options as you may accidentally perform fresh install formatting you whole system, check "Third party packages" option.
3. On some machines, the system will not have working connectivity after the install has completed.
4. Connect LAN or USB Tether internet from phone to Laptop.
5. Run "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade" from terminal.
6. After all the update, reboot system.
7. You will have working system in most cases.
8. If you are the unlucky one, and your Wireless Internet does not work.
9. Install appropriate "kernal driver" for you wirless card.
10. For Nvidia Drivers, just goto System Settings > Software & Update > Additional Drivers > check the one you want to replace.

Thanks, let me know if you still need help.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have done exactly that five times now, which is why I thought it had to be some other issue that a fresh install would not address. I’ll give that another go following the order you laid out and see if that clears up my issues.

Comment: Yes, give it a other try with proper steps, I have T470 with Nvidia Card, I was able to install Ubuntu normally.

Comment: I am still getting the same issue where I can boot about 25% of the time, but cannot reliably boot every single time yet. I have also tried using the steps outlined here as well, which helped with the brightness issues: https://penguinlinguist.wordpress.com/2014/08/14/setting-up-ubuntu-on-a-thinkpad-t430/